# Missing Data: Profile or Pattern?

Tags: statistical-significance, terminology, missing-data

In missing data analysis: is the term "missing profile" the same as "missing pattern". I think they are the same; but when I Google for "missing profile" together with missing data I don't get too many hits. Any reference where the term "Missing Profile" is used or defined ?

Comment: I never heard of these terms. "Missing at random" is the least troublesome kind.

Comment: Missing at random is a mechanism of missing data, my question is about patterns of profiles of missing data: for example Item or Unit profile of pattern.